# How can i use serializable transactions on Java EE 6?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I am learning the new annotations for transaction management, like `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)`, but i could not find out how to create a transaction with **SERIALIZABLE isolation**. Is this possible on a per-method basis or i have to set it on the connection for the whole application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally transaction isolation level is set on `Connection`, per application.

However, e.g. in Spring on Weblogic server, you can set isolation level per transaction. See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html), point 9.8.1.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible on a per-method basis or i have to set it on the connection for the whole application?

This is not possible in a standardized way, this is not covered by the EJB specification.

But some containers do offer support for this as mentioned in
[How can I set isolation levels per method in EJB 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585968/how-can-i-set-isolation-levels-per-method-in-ejb-3).